# Clipping path seems to be outside of text

Tags: pdf, clipping

recently I wanted to construct a PDF document which should have text clipping: With *4 Tr* I tried to define the text as clipping area. But when I wanted to fill the lower part of the text with red color, the result was reversed.

Do anyone knows, why?

Thanks for any answer!

```
stream
BT
 4 8 Td
 0.8 0.2 0.7 rg    % Writing lila.
 4 Tr              % Fill & Use text as clipping area.
 /TR 32 Tf
 (Hallo Welt) Tj
 1 0 0 rg          % Fill in red.
 0 0 200 20 re F   % <- Mistake?
ET
```

What I wanted to have:

[image: What I wanted to have]

What I got:

[image: What I got]

Comment: Clipping only happens at `ET`. `re` and `F` strictly said are invalid between `BT` and `ET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

> The behaviour of the clipping modes requires further explanation. Glyph outlines shall begin accumulating if a **BT** operator is executed while the text rendering mode is set to a clipping mode or if it is set to a clipping mode within a text object. Glyphs shall accumulate until the text object is ended by an **ET** operator; the text rendering mode shall not be changed back to a nonclipping mode before that point.
>
> *(section 9.3.6* Text Rendering Mode *)*

In your sample you don't wait until the **ET** for the clipping path to take effect. So, when you are painting the red rectangle, your special clipping path is not yet in effect.

---

Furthermore your operation sequence actually is invalid! Neither path construction nor path painting operators (i.e. neither your `0 0 200 20 re` nor your `F`) are allowed inside a text object, cf. *Figure 9 – Graphics Objects* in the [specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf):

[image: Figure 9 – Graphics Objects]

Thus, strictly speaking your PDF viewer had better refuse to draw your content stream at all.

Comment: @Jongware *OP needs to draw the text two times* - he tried to do that  using text rendering mode 4 to **Fill text and add to path for clipping** and then overwriting the lower text half using the rectangle clipped to that text path. Unfortunately in the wrong operator order, though.

Comment: Ah, the text path is the clip area, not (as I thought) the rectangle. Hm hah. My method seemed so much easier 

Comment: Erg - bad mistake. Thank you very much, mkl!